# SumIfs conditional array criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, conditional-statements, sumifs

I have a simple formula like: `IFERROR(SUM(SUMIFS(TBL1[SUMCOLUMN],TBL1[ACTIVITY],{"0001","0002","0003"})),0)` and it works.

But I want the `{"0001","0002","0003"}` part to be different based on the value of a column so I change the formula to:

```
IFERROR(SUM(SUMIFS(TBL1[SUMCOLUMN],TBL1[ACTIVITY],IF([@TYPE]="EHT",{"0001","0002","0005"},IF([@TYPE]="CT",{"0003","0004","0007"},"0010")))),0)
```

And it gives me values only based on the first array value.
Example:

```
IF([@TYPE]="EHT",{"0001","0002","0005"} //Gives me sum of only where "0001" and ignores "0002","0005" 
IF([@TYPE]="CT",{"0003","0004","0007"} //Gives me sum of only where "0003" and ignores "0004","0007"
```

I thought excel is converting the critera into text so I have played around with different methods like using char(34), different number of quotes, putting values in different cells and referencing but no help.
Any idea what I am missing?

Sample tables:
TBL1:

```
SUMCOLUMN   ACTIVITY
5           0001
20          0002
50          0003
...

TBL2:
TYPE        TOTAL
EHT         SUMIFS GOES HERE
CT          SUMIFS GOES HERE
OTHER       SUMIFS GOES HERE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know WHY it is doing that - it's very annoying.
But in your particular case would this work:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(
  IF([@TYPE]="EHT",SUMIFS(TBL1[SUMCOLUMN],TBL1[ACTIVITY],{"0001","0002","0005"}),0),
  IF([@TYPE]="CT",SUMIFS(TBL1[SUMCOLUMN],TBL1[ACTIVITY],",{"0003","0004","0007"}),0),
  SUMIFS(TBL1[SUMCOLUMN],TBL1[ACTIVITY],"0010")
),0)
```

Since SUMIFS returns an array of results and you are summing them, instead of trying to make the criteria conditional make the whole SUMIFS conditional.

Comment: Thank you.
It solves the problem.
Only thing is I have few other criterias and using this solution makes the formula needlessly big.
Hopefully someone will let me know why my solution is not working properly.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but I recently had to do something very similar and I randomly came across this question.

I tried your formula and it works perfectly fine when I `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` the formula in.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(SUM(
  IF([@TYPE]="EHT",SUMIFS(TBL1[SUMCOLUMN],TBL1[ACTIVITY],{"0001","0002","0005"}),0),
  IF([@TYPE]="CT",SUMIFS(TBL1[SUMCOLUMN],TBL1[ACTIVITY],",{"0003","0004","0007"}),0),
  SUMIFS(TBL1[SUMCOLUMN],TBL1[ACTIVITY],"0010")
),0)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30101438)